Transformer modelling / coupled inductors
I provided a picture which shows the transformer model and related equations.

[Transformer Model and Equations]
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrIfvNVBSyE
I have 2 questions which are as follows:

In the beginning of V2 equation in the picture where does the n.Lm come from?

As far as I know the mutual inductance (M) is defined as M12= (N1.Q1)/i2 or M21= (N2.Q2)/i1 where Q is magnetic flux, i is current and N is number of turns. The mutual inductance defined as M=n.Lm in the picture. I didn’t understand the relationship between the above equation that I wrote and n.Lm? How should I reach from above equations to n.Lm?




In the beginnig of V2 equation in the picture where does the n.Lm come from ?

The inductor's voltage-current relationship is:-
$$
v_L = L \ \frac{di_L}{dt}
$$
The voltage across the primary magnetising inductance, \$L_m\$, is therefore
$$
v_{L_m}=L_m \ \frac{d}{dt}(i_1-n\ i_2)
$$
Since the primary-to-secondary conversion ratio is 1:n, the voltage across the secondary winding will be \$n\$ times \$v_{L_m}\$:
$$
v_{sec}=n \ v_{L_m} = n \ L_m \ \frac{d}{dt}(i_1-n\ i_2)
$$
Finally, if you write the KVL for the secondary taking the polarities of both the secondary winding and the leakage, you'll get the \$v_2\$ voltage as shown in the picture:
$$
-v_{sec}+v_{L_{k2}}+v_2 = 0 \\
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow v_2&=v_{sec}-v_{L_{k2}}\\
&=n \ L_m \ \frac{d}{dt}(i_1-n\ i_2) - L_{k2} \ \frac{di_2}{dt}
\end{align}
$$

I didnt understand the relationship between the above equation that I wrote and n.Lm ?

A change in primary current results in a change in the secondary voltage, thanks to the presence of the mutual inductance:
$$
v_{sec}=M \ \frac{di_{pri}}{dt}
$$
where \$v_{sec}\$ is the voltage across the secondary winding, \$i_{pri}\$ is the current flowing through the primary winding, and \$M\$ is the mutual inductance. Now if you apply this to the relationships above
$$
v_{sec}=M \ \frac{di_{L_m}}{dt}=M \ \frac{d}{dt}(i_1-n\ i_2)
$$
We know that \$v_{sec} = n \ v_{L_{L_m}}\$ (see the 3rd equation above), therefore
$$
M = n \ L_m
$$

Thank you for your answer sir, I understand it. Thus we understand that the mutual inductance is not always expressed as M12= (N1.Q1)/i2 or M21= (N2.Q2)/i1 as we see in the case  M=n.Lm , isn't it ? @Rohat Kılıç

@Mhan it's still the result of $M=N \ \Phi / i$, bit with a little bit more math.
